# What are the situations which can cause a resistor to permanently increase its resistance?

Tags: resistors, hvdc

The resistance of a resistor in the HVDC circuit permanently increases.

Is it because of voltage or some other reasons?

Note that there are no short circuit cases seen in the system.

Comment: as i see it, the most common is vaporization of the resistor when the heat generated by the v*i is too much. the resistance will approach infinity, at times accompanied with fire

Comment: Check the datasheet for the part, resistors have a voltage rating as well as a power one, and you need to stay within both the limits. Also consider any startup transients, again resistors have (if you dig a bit with the manufacturer) a rating for this together (if a good one) with a spec for how much you can expect the value to change when abused this way.

Comment: @Ruperto thank you for the reply but the wattage of the resistor is high. As dan says it might be voltage.

Comment: @DanMills yes I am trying to get the datasheet it can be a voltage problem as you said.
Thanks a lot for the help.
I thought resistors only open/short when they get damages this variance in resistance thing is new for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carbon resistors (e.g. anode loads in valve amplifiers) that run hot, dissipating at least half of their nominal power rating, can increase in value by 30-50% or so over prolonged use, and should be replaced every 40 years or so.

In that case, prolonged operation at high temperature is the problem. As you say nothing about the type of resistor, or the power rating, or the voltage, this may or may not apply to your situation.

Comment: You are really great.

The resistor which we use are Metal film but the environment in which they operate can be 40-50deg.

Can that affect the resistance over log period of time?

Comment: Address that question to the mfg, along with the environment and resistor's operating temperature.

Comment: Okay, and thanks a lot for the help.